# Syntax error or access violation: 1064, trying to use left join

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am trying to make a join in a MySQL query. I need to join various tables to show some information, so I tried using this code:

```
$q = intval($_GET['q']);
try {
    $results = $db->query('select empresas.nombreHotel,
        ubiacion.ubiacion,
        empresas.idUbicacion,
        ubiacion.idUbicacion
        from empresas where idRangoPrecio="' . $q .'",
        left join ubiacion
        on empresas.idUbicacion=ubiacion.ubiacion' );

} catch(Exception $e){
    echo $e->getMessage();
    die();
}
$empresasLeyenda = $results->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

But I keep getting the same error:

> SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an
>   error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your
>   MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ' left join
>   ubiacion on empresas.idUbicacion=ubiacion.ubiacion' at line 5

Comment: thanks now the error changed "SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'left join ubiacion on empresas.idUbicacion=ubiacion.ubiacion' at line 6"

Comment: FYI, you are wide open to [**SQL injection**](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection).

Answer (score 4):

It's:

```
SELECT ..
FROM ...
JOIN ...
WHERE ...
```

You have the `join` and `where` clauses reversed.

Comment: thanks but keep getting error "SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'left join ubiacion on empresas.idUbicacion=ubiacion.ubiacion f' at line 5"

Comment: wouldn't surprise me if you have an [sql injection attack](http://bobby-tables.com) issue as well. what exactly as you passing in for the `$_GET['q']` value?

Comment: is an integer like 5 or 6

Comment: @alfonsopeñaranda The `f` at the end of that error message says you have things out of order still. It's `SELECT ... FROM ... LEFT JOIN ... ON ... WHERE ...`.

Comment: so i changed the order as you said but now i got more confuse : "SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'mihotel.co.ubiacion' doesn't exist"

Comment: you really need to learn how to do basic debugging yourself. We're happy to help, we're not here to spoonfeed you the answer to every minor little problem that you really really need to learn how to fix yourself.

Comment: thanks @MarcB ,I tried a lot of stuff this is my last resource, im been trying to understand the error by myself but it have been 1 week since im stuck whit it. sorry for my bad english.

Answer (score 1):

You have an extra `,` in your query and also your statements are not in correct order. Please use:

```
$q = intval($_GET['q']);

try {
    $results = $db->query('select empresas.nombreHotel,
        ubiacion.ubiacion,
        empresas.idUbicacion,
        ubiacion.idUbicacion
        from empresas
        left join ubiacion
        on empresas.idUbicacion=ubiacion.ubiacion
        where idRangoPrecio="' . $q .'"' );

} catch(Exception $e){
    echo $e->getMessage();
    die();
}
$empresasLeyenda = $results->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Comment: You should explain *why* this is a solution, not just offer up a code blob. The code blob is not helpful by itself.

Comment: @EdCottrell OK, I explained the changes. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It is a personal preference I know but I find it easier to assign an alias to each of the tables and use the alias when referencing fields. As noted earlier, your where clause is in the rwong place, perhaps the following might be suitable:-

```
$sql='select 
    e.`nombreHotel`,
    e.`idUbicacion`,
    u.`ubiacion`,
    u.`idUbicacion`
    from `empresas` e
    left join `ubiacion`u on e.`idUbicacion`=u.`idUbicacion`
    where e.`idRangoPrecio`="' . $q .'"';
```